# Magento 2 - Get random results with Elasticsuit Catalog Fulltext Product Collection

Tags: product, collection, product-collection, elasticsearch, random

I am using a Magesuite module to get a product collection, and among other things I want to randomly select a certain number of products, fitting of course some criteria set with filters.

The collection used in this case is of class `\Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection`. In this collection type, `orderRand()` does not work, as it merely randomizes the results that are firstly fetched by ElasticSearch. I'd like for a way to instruct the collection, if possible, to randomize the results before fetching the products, according to the rest of the criteria specified.

Comment: Why you creating your own method ? Get the full base collection then use the php rand method to pick collection ids between 0 and your collection size ?

Comment: @Claims The piece I want to modify is an already existing carousel, in the Magesuite module, as I mention, and I am supposed to add yet another section on it. The carousel code uses the above collection type, so I am "forced" to use it or else do extensive overriding. The code I am writing is a filter added to the collection, and not the entire processing of the collection, which is mainly done in another core Magesuite file. That other file also does the final picking of a certain number of results, and it is Elasticsearch that does the picking and not SQL, so it is pre-fetch.